# electron-builder fails building linux package on macos - Error: Unknown target: build

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I'm using `electron-builder` to package my application. I have a `dist/` folder where all resources are. `main.js` in root folder does not need any transpiling and includes main process code. This works well in development mode when launching using `electron` command.

I have `electron-builder` set up using `package.json` configuration:

```
  [...]
  "main": "./main.js",
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.electron.mycompany.myapp",
    "productName": "myapp",
    "linux": {
      "target": "deb"
    },
    "files": [
      "./dist",
      "./main.js"
    ]
  },
  [...]
```

I'm launching `electron-builder` like this: `electron-builder -ml build`. Macos build packages fine and I'm able to launch the application. However Linux build fails. I'm building Linux package on macos Catalina. It gives me error stack trace:

```
rebuilding native dependencies  dependencies=leveldown@5.6.0 platform=linux arch=x64
  ⨯ Unknown target: build  stackTrace=
                             Error: Unknown target: build
                                 at createCommonTarget (/Users/username/Projects/myappnode_modules/app-builder-lib/src/targets/targetFactory.ts:90:11)
                                 at /Users/username/Projects/myapp/node_modules/app-builder-lib/src/linuxPackager.ts:65:18
                                 at mapper (/Users/username/Projects/myapp/node_modules/app-builder-lib/src/targets/targetFactory.ts:57:16)
                                 at LinuxPackager.createTargets (/Users/username/Projects/myapp/node_modules/app-builder-lib/src/linuxPackager.ts:63:7)
                                 at createTargets (/Users/username/Projects/myapp/node_modules/app-builder-lib/src/targets/targetFactory.ts:64:12)
                                 at Packager.doBuild (/Users/username/Projects/myapp/node_modules/app-builder-lib/src/packager.ts:442:28)
                                 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
                                 at executeFinally (/Users/username/Projects/myapp/node_modules/builder-util/src/promise.ts:12:14)
                                 at Packager._build (/Users/username/Projects/myapp/node_modules/app-builder-lib/src/packager.ts:373:31)
                                 at Packager.build (/Users/username/Projects/myapp/node_modules/app-builder-lib/src/packager.ts:337:12)
                                 at executeFinally (/Users/username/Projects/myapp/node_modules/builder-util/src/promise.ts:12:14)
  • building embedded block map  file=dist/IJP Visualization Tool-1.0.0-alpha.1-mac.zip
```

I am not using any code signing (nor do I wish to). Is something misconfigured? It seems to be it but not sure what the problem is exactly.

Comment: I believe you do not have to append `build`. My package builds just fine (on Linux, though) using `electron-builder -ml`...

Comment: It does not explain that Mac build is able to finish but not Linux

Comment: I have added an answer with an explanation of the behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [`electron-builder` CLI documentation](https://www.electron.build/cli), all platform switches accept a "target list", which in essence is what you configure in your `package.json` with your different platform entries (`build.<platform>.target`, e.g. `build.linux.target`).

However, by using these target lists, you can specify which targets you want to build and exclude all others. Since Linux' switch is the last in the switch list `-ml`, Electron Builder interprets this as though you want to pass it a target list. This does not apply to the macOS build step because then you would have to use `-m <targets> -l <targets>`, `-ml <targets>` apparently only applies to Linux.

Thus, by appending `build` to the command line, you tell Electron Builder to compile all configured targets for macOS but only build the Linux target called `build`. Since there is no such target, Electron Builder crashes. Removing `build` from your command will do the trick.